# Composition of Cartesian product is Cartesian

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $X_1,X_2, X_3$ and $Y$ be schemes over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f_1:X_1 \to Y, f_2:X_2 \to Y$ and $f_3:X_3 \to X_2$ be three morphism of schemes. Under the composition map $f_2 \circ f_3$ from $X_3$ to $Y$, is it true that the Cartesian product $X_3 \times_Y X_1$ is isomorphic to $X_3 \times_{X_2} (X_1 \times_Y X_2)$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, indeed it is a property of categorical pullback in any category. You can construct "towers" of pullbacks and still get a pullback. More precisely, if you have a commutative diagram

[image]

where the right hand square is a pullback, then: 
the left hand square is a pullback if and only if the big square is
a pullback.

Comment: Nice answer. It sometimes makes me feel surprised that isomorphisms like this don't really have anything to do with schemes.

Comment: @user38268: I agree! it is the power of categories and universal constructions inside them...

Comment: Oh one thing I have found to be very useful when dealing with fibered products has been the magic square. If you want to convert a statement about quasiseparated schemes to a statement about the intersection of two affines being compact, the magic square does it almost immediately!

Comment: Can you please give me a reference for this "magic square" and the application you were mentioning? I am afraid I never heard about it!

Comment: @user38268 I totally agree with you. But its also cool to note that essentially scheme theoretic notions boil down to this theorem such as that properness it stable under pullback.